# In Model I/O documented API is missing in the provided libraries. What is the work around?

Tags: swift, scenekit, modelio

Although documented the following `MDLAsset` class methods do not exist in the `ModelIO` library:

```
+ assetWithSCNScene:bufferAllocator:



+ assetWithSCNScene:
```

So, currently there is no way to read in a `SceneKit` **.scn** file and create an `MDLAsset`.

What is the work around?

### UPDATE 0

I am importing these:

```
import SceneKit
import ModelIO
import MetalKit
import GLKit
```

In my renderer I attempt to instantiate an `MDLAsset` from an `SCNScene`:

```
guard let scene = SCNScene(named:"ball.scn") else {
    fatalError("Error: Can not create scene")
}

let asset = MDLAsset(scnScene:scene, bufferAllocator:MTKMeshBufferAllocator(device: device))
```

I get this error

[image]

Indicating the category cannot be found. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are defined as a category on `MDLAsset` by SceneKit (which is necessary, because that's where `SCNScene` is defined). You need to `@import SceneKit` as well as `@import ModelIO`.

---

You'd listed the signatures in ObjC; didn't note that you'd tagged it Swift. In Swift, you need to import the relevant submodule:

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

That's actually a bit strange IMO, and probably shouldn't be necessary. I'd open a radar (bugreport.apple.com). At the very least, the docs need to be clearer.

Comment: Hi Rob. Do you have working Metal code that reads in a .scn file using these API calls?

Comment: Bingo! Thanks so much Rob.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing and matching three different frameworks, that's why the category isn't working.

MTKMeshBufferAllocator is part of MetalKit, and SceneKit won't know what to do with the allocation.

Just leave off the bufferAllocator and you should be fine.

```
let asset = MDLAsset(scnScene:scene)
```

On the question of importing,

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

gives you the bridging API's. It's purpose is to allow you to construct SCN objects from MDL objects.

Comment: This was answered a year ago. What new value does your answer bring?

Comment: The new value is in correcting Rob's statement that importing the file shouldn't be necessary. Importing SceneKit.ModelIO is necessary in order to move a Model IO asset into SceneKit. (FWIW I architected ModelIO and the SceneKit bridge.)

Comment: Well it could probably be added as a comment to his answer then, but alright, fair enough, it provides useful information about what was asked.

Comment: That's what I had intended :) I'm a stackoverflow n00b... I will pay attention to that workflow in the future. I should also point out that there is also the bufferAllocator issue not addressed in Rob's statement, I'm hoping that will be useful to others in future visits to this question.